# jQuery fade down without losing container space

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I have 3 `cards` lined up horizontally, and am sliding them downwards and fading them at the same time. What I would like to do next is keep the space on the page after the animation. I know that `css('visibility','hidden')` does not remove the element from the document, but if I apply this property after the animation it is too late.

I tried to save off the original width and height of the `card` and reapplying them using `.css()` after the animation and this did not work.

HTML

```
<div class="row center">
                    <div  id="card1" class="col s4">
                        <div  class="card blue-grey lighten-2">
                            <div class="card-content white-text center">
                                <span class="card-title">Card 1</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4">
                        <div class="card blue-grey lighten-2">
                            <div class="card-content white-text center">
                                <span class="card-title">Card 2</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4">
                        <div  class="card blue-grey lighten-2">
                            <div class="card-content white-text center">
                                <span class="card-title">Card 3</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#card1")
    .css('opacity', 1)
    .css('visibility','hidden')
    .animate({
        opacity: 0,
        marginTop: $("#card1").height(),
        height: "toggle",
    }, 2500, function () {
        //when animation is done
    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00wswmqb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform: translate()` instead of `margin` and toggling `height`. You can also animate everything in CSS by applying a class in JS.

```js
    $("#card1")
        .addClass('ready');
```

```css
#card1 {
  transition: opacity 2.5s, transform 2.5s;
}
.ready {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row center">
                    <div  id="card1" class="col s4">
                        <div  class="card blue-grey lighten-2">
                            <div class="card-content white-text center">
                                <span class="card-title">Card 1</span>
                              
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4">
                        <div class="card blue-grey lighten-2">
                            <div class="card-content white-text center">
                                <span class="card-title">Card 2</span>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4">
                        <div  class="card blue-grey lighten-2">
                            <div class="card-content white-text center">
                                <span class="card-title">Card 3</span>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh9zh2xu/1/)

Comment: Forked my jsfiddle and put it in your answer, seems to work well (running code snippet in stack doesn't show what you want). I am going to play with it a bit to make sure it completely answers my questions. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's hiding because a `display: none` styling is being added to it after the animation is done. I don't usually like using `!important` but adding some simple styling fixed it up:

https://jsfiddle.net/00wswmqb/1/